# npm config set C compiler not to vcbuild.exe

Tags: windows, gcc, npm, cygwin

When trying to `npm install` a node project in a **Windows7** machine I am suffering from the inglorious error message:

> MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.

Because I am under **Cygwin** I have already installed **gcc** (`$ gcc -v` and `$ g++ -v` respond in both Cygwin and cmd).

How can I tell npm to use **gcc** to compile instead of the **vcbuild.exe** that I don't have installed?

Note: I have already tried **node-gyp** and it did not work.

Note2: I know for sure the code runs without problems in linux.

Comment: cygwin is not linux , so you can not expect that sotware not configured will run. npm requires nodejs; have you ported it to cygwin ?

Comment: I installed node with the usual installer for windows and during the installation it gives you the option to install npm as well. After that node and npm are fully manageable from Cyqwin as cmd. I am having trouble with VCBuild.exe and I wonder if there were another solution than installing the heavy VS.

Comment: Manageable from cygwin as windows cmd is one thing. But it is a cygwin program ? I doubt. If so you can not use cygwin gcc for compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what sorted out my problem and the steps that I took to reach the long-awaited solution:

1. Installed [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) but the VCBuild.exe was not there still.
2. Installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015 and tried to install the affected module as: `npm install bcrypt --msvs_version=2015` but I got the following error:

> error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".

3. My last shot was to install Visual [Studio Express for Desktop](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) and after `npm install bcrypt --msvs_version=2015` I manage to `npm install` and `npm start` my app in Windows7!!
4. Lastly I uninstalled Visual Studio Community and Microsoft Build Tools 2015.

Note I had to remove the **bcrypt** module from the dependencies in package.json and install it as `npm install bcrypt --msvs_version=2015` inside my app folder.